# Extracting information from same page popup in python Selenium webscraping

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Note : I'm experienced in python however just starting out in selenium and webscraping. Please excuse if this is a bad question or if my fundamentals in selenium seem amiss. I could not find an answer in hours of searching hence i ask here

Goal: To extract the "About the Business" information found in Yelp pages of businesses
Some pages have their about the business information within a Read More button based popup (eg : https://www.yelp.com/biz/and-pizza-bethesda-bethesda)
Some pages do not have their business information in a Read More button based popup (eg : https://www.yelp.com/biz/pneuma-fashions-upper-marlboro-3 )

Problem: Unable to navigate to the About the Business popup that appears after clicking the Read More button and extract the text present in it.

Attempts as of now: From googling I had found explanations on how to handle alert popups or window popups. However the code doesnt work. The popup that emerges when clicking Read More button does not cause change in window_handles

```
    import re
    # getting all sections of the page
    result=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("section")
    About = None
    for sec in result:
    if sec.text.startswith("About the Business"):
        # this pertains only to the About the business section
        
        main_page=driver.current_window_handle
        print(main_page) # Returns the current handle
        
        sec.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
        popup=None
        for handle in driver.window_handles: # is an iterable with only one handle 
            # The only handle present is the main_page handle
            print(handle) 
            if handle!=main_page:
                popup = handle
        print(popup) # returns None
        driver.switch_to.window(popup) # Throws error because popup=None

# THE FOLLOWING SECTION IS NOT EXECUTED BECAUSE OF THE ERROR ABOVE
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        button_contents=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("p")
        for b in button_contents:
            print(b.text) # intended to print text contents
        close=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
        close.click()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_page)
```

Please help

Thank you to everyone who reads this question and provides advice and answers

Answer (score 0):

One thing that u should know is that the pop-up is not displayed in a new window. It is instead displayed in the same page itself. Here is the complete code to extract the text from the pop-up:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/and-pizza-bethesda-bethesda')

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrap"]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/section[5]/div[2]/button').click()

    p1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-portal-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/p').text

    p2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-portal-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p[2]').text

    print("Specialties --",p1)
    print("History --",p2)

except:
    print('Read more button not found')
```

Output:

```
Specialties -- Award-winning pizza: Named one of Fast Company's "World's Most Innovative Companies" in 2018, third-place in the Washington Post Express's of "Best Fast Casual" in 2018, third place in the Washington City Paper's "Best Gluten-Free Menu" in 2018 and won its "Best Pizza in D.C." in 2017, 11th on TripAdvisor's "Best Fast Casual Restaurants -- United States" in 2018.
History -- Since 2012, we've built pizza shops with an edge to their craft pies, beverages and shop design, created an environment where ALL of our Tribe can thrive, supported our local communities and now we'll text you back, if you want. Started with a pizza shop. Became a culture. That's &pizza.
```

Edit:

Since this doesn't work with [this](https://www.yelp.com/biz/asian-bakery-cafe-rockville) website, replace the first `find_element_by_xpath` with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lemon--div__373c0__1mboc border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU']/button[.='Read more']").click()
```

This works for both the websites.

Comment: Hi, i tried this type of method of using xpath but the problem is this does not generalise well and work on other business pages. For example, it breaks for this business page link < https://www.yelp.com/biz/asian-bakery-cafe-rockville >

Comment: Replace the first ```find_element_by_xpath``` with ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lemon--div__373c0__1mboc border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU']/button[.='Read more']").click()```

Comment: This should definitely work. I have also added the same to my post. Check it out.

Comment: Sir, the changed version works in terms of clicking of button but it fails to extract the text of Specialities and History (i.e p1 and p2). I believe this is because xpath changes between different web pages for businesses. Is it possible to get the text data is a more generalised manner using class name or something?

Comment: This website is very strange. The class names are different for each webpage, the xpaths are different for each webpage, the css selectors are different for each webpage. Nothing could be found in common. I will try my best to help u. But this is probably the toughest website that I have ever tried to scrape. BTW, pls refrain from calling me as "sir", coz I'm just a 9th grader!!!!!!!

Comment: lol, ive tried getting the whole section of the popup text using ``` driver.find_elements_by_class_name("lemon--div__373c0__1mboc padding-t2__373c0__11Iek padding-r2__373c0__28zpp padding-b2__373c0__34gV1 padding-l2__373c0__1Dr82 border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU")``` But its does not return anything and produces errors

Comment: It is bcs the class name is different in each website. I really have no clue about how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is a custom pop-up so you won't need to switch to it. I suggest to study about getting [relative xpath](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) . Use loop to navigate to your urls and include below code

```js
driver.get(your_URL)

readMoreBtnXpath= "//h4[text()='About the Business']/ancestor::section//button"
aboutTheBusinessSec = "//h4[text()='About the Business']/ancestor::section"
fromTheBusinessSec = "((//h2[text()='From the business']/parent::div/following-sibling::div//div)[5]/div)[last()]/preceding-sibling::div"

try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, readMoreBtnXpath).click()
    button_contents = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, fromTheBusinessSec)
    for b in button_contents:
            print(b.text)
except:
    print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, aboutTheBusinessSec).text)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The code you have provided seems be not work on the case of other business pages. Eg: https://www.yelp.com/biz/asian-bakery-cafe-rockville

Comment: It's working fine on my end. Do you encounter any error?